# path error for tree tagger with koRpus R package

Tags: r, windows, path, text-mining, pos-tagger

I try to use treeTagger that I installed from [here](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/#Windows) in R with the package koRpus.

```
library(koRpus)
tagged.results <- treetag(as.factor("salut ça va"), treetagger="manual", lang="fr", TT.options=list(path="C:\\TreeTagger\\bin\\tree-tagger.exe"))
```

generates the following error :

```
Erreur dans path.expand(path) : argument 'path' incorrect
```

Which I don't understand because I can see all the files in this path, which are : tree-tagger and tree-tagger-flush (application files), tag-french and chunk-french which are windows command file.

I also tried :

```
set.kRp.env(TT.cmd="C:\\TreeTagger\\bin\\tree-tagger.exe", lang="fr")
tagged.text <- treetag(as.factor("salut ça va"),lang="fr")
```

The second generates the same error

Comment: Looking a the documentation it says "path Mandatory: The absolute path to the TreeTagger root directory. That is where its subfolders bin, cmd and lib are located." Can you try changing the path to just "C:\\TreeTagger"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues here. First the as.factor("salut ca va") should be a file with that text in it. You are also missing a preset value inside of TT.options. You will want to put preset="fr" after the path argument. Finally the path itself should point to the root directory.

The documentation [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/koRpus/docs/treetag) states "TT.options
A list of options to configure how TreeTagger is called. You have two basic choices: Either you choose one of the pre-defined presets or you give a full set of valid options:
path Mandatory: The absolute path to the TreeTagger root directory. That is where its subfolders bin, cmd and lib are located."

You are pointing the path variable inside of the bin directory to the .exe file. Run the following code to point to the root directory where the bin directory is located as follows:

```
library(koRpus)
tagged.results <- treetag("test.txt", treetagger="manual", lang="fr", TT.options=list(path="C:\\TreeTagger", preset="fr"))
```

Comment: still not working, actually I tried every path possible in this arborescence, I don't undestand, if you have another idea... thanks anyway

Comment: @StéphanieC Can you save the text "salut ca va" to a .txt file locally and try to point to that instead of using as.factor("salut ca va")? I am curious to see if the error is actually with the windows path or with this argument.

Comment: The error message changed ! `> tagged.results <- treetag("test.txt", treetagger="manual", lang="fr", TT.options=list(path="C:\\TreeTagger"))
Erreur dans stop(simpleError(paste("Manual TreeTagger configuration demanded, but not enough optinons given!\nMissing options:",  : 
  mauvais message d'erreur`

Comment: I am looking at the sample from the doc because I can not test right now but the only difference I see is that you do not have your preset argument inside TT.options. Can you set preset="fr" inside TT.options likes so: tagged.results <- treetag("test.txt", treetagger="manual", lang="fr", TT.options=list(path="C:\\TreeTagger", preset="fr"))

Comment: I've made some progress, looking in more details about how to use treetagger outside of R with windows, I found a cmd that does'nt generate the same error `set.kRp.env(TT.cmd="C:\\TreeTagger\\bin\\tag-french.bat", lang="fr")
tagged.results <- treetag("test.txt")` but still an error `In readLines(takeAsFile, encoding = encoding) :
  ligne finale incomplète trouvée dans 'C:\Users\stephanie\Downloads\test.txt'` which means final line is incomplete, which I don't explain now

Comment: apparantly this is a warning but it worked anyway ! thanks for your interest !

Comment: I had to changed the name of a file but it worked too ! thx a lot

Comment: if you're bored i have a trickier question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210346/how-can-i-use-aspell-with-r-with-a-specific-language